# Parsing Json Data in ListView using Volley

Tags: listview, android-volley, android-json

I got my data in listview but not in the way I expect for. I want to obtain the data in listview but it is making list with above static view [like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR63R.png)

Any idea, how am I getting it?
Is there also something to do with layout?

**This is my MainActivity:**

```
private List<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
private ListView listView;
private Adapter adapter;

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new Adapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.Number1);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.ServiceName1);
    textView3 = findViewById(R.id.Amount1);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    jsonParse();

  }

    public void jsonParse() {

    final String fetchurl = ("https://xelwel.com.np/hamrosewaapp/api/get_organization_list");

    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, fetchurl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("org_list");

                UserInfo info = new UserInfo();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject patient = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    info.setId(patient.getString("orga_orgid"));
                    info.setName(patient.getString("orga_organame"));

                    list.add(info);
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("api_key", "123456789");
            return params;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

**And this is my Adapter class:**

```
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<UserInfo> DataList;

public Adapter(Activity activity, List<UserInfo> dataitem) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.DataList = dataitem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return DataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return DataList.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

    TextView id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.Number1);
    TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ServiceName1);

    UserInfo m = DataList.get(position);

    id.setText(m.getId());
    name.setText(m.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

**This is my Item Layout file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Civil Service Hospital"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SerialNo."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Textview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="S.No."
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/SerialNo."
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SerialNo."
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Service Name"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:text="Amount"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Number1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SerialNo."
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ServiceName1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ServiceName1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ServiceName1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Amount1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Amount"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Amount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Amount"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Please commit my mistake that I got with this code...

Comment: Please Post the Whole MainActivity

Comment: @Chandan I edit my MainActivity. Please check out my problem...

Comment: Found some issues? Is there something can be done with layout/xml file...?

Answer (score 0):

Check This Out of MainActivity. Object of UserInfo should be created in For Loop.

```
final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
fetchurl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("org_list");



            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject patient = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
                info.setId(patient.getString("orga_orgid"));
                info.setName(patient.getString("orga_organame"));

                list.add(info);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("api_key", "123456789");
        return params;
    }
};

requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the data from Id 1 but the view is still the same. It is still taking above layout and making listview with that... I want to show the above static view as static and below as dynamic. Do you know the solution of this problem...? I have also edited question, you can view the current output result...

Comment: Can u post your Item xml File.

Comment: And in main activity layout I used only Listview inside of RelativeLayout.. Can something more should be add over here...?

Comment: Got any idea...? How to make it?

Comment: Man I got it! I just put static view in mainlayout then it happens. I have post my answer.. Thank you man for being there...

Comment: @ Chandan I had posted a question before 2 days but it still remain unanswered. I post once and wait for whole day and again I delete it and post it again but no one is there to answer my question. Would you please help me for that question which remain unanswered...? I'll be waiting for your response...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my answer by myself. I just check out and put static view in mainActivitylayout and dynamic view in item_layout and it happens. Below is my mainlayout xml file that I used:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Number1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SerialNo."
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ServiceName1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ServiceName1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ServiceName1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Amount1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Amount"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Amount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Amount"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you @Chandan Kushwaha for supporting my question...

Comment: Great @Ayush Katuwal

Comment: You are Welcome!!